# Meteor- User can only upvote or downvote once

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-autoform

I have working upvotes and downvotes on my meteor app but the user is able to upvote and downvote as much as they want. I am trying to make it so they can only do one and if they do the other it removes the previous.

My Autoform looks as followed:

```
ArticleSchema  = new SimpleSchema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    label: "Article title",
    autoform: {
      placeholder: "full article title here"
    }
  },
  url:{
    type: String,
    label:  "URL",
    autoform: {
      placeholder: "http://website.com"
    }
  },
  username:{
    type: String,
    label: "Author",
    autoValue: function() {
      return Meteor.user().username
  }
},
  author:{
    type: String,
    label: "Author",
    autoValue: function() {
      return this.userId
  },
  autoform: {
    type: "hidden"
  }
},
  autoform: {
    type: "hidden"
  }
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    label: "Created At",
    autoValue: function(){
      return new Date()
    },
    autoform: {
      type: "hidden"
    }
  },
  upvote: {
    type:Number,
    optional:true
  },
  upVoters:{
    type:Array,
    optional:true
  },
  'upVoters.$':{
    type:String
  },
  downvote: {
    type:Number,
    optional:true
  },
  downVoters:{
    type:Array,
    optional:true
  },
  'downVoters.$':{
    type:String
  },
});
```

My events:

```
Template.articleOutput.events({
  "click .upvote": function(){
    var articles = Articles.findOne({ _id: this._id });
    if( articles ) {
      if (_.contains(articles.downVoters, this.userId)) {
        Articles.update({
             _id: this._id
          },
          {
            $pull: {
              downVoters: this.userId
            },
            $addToSet: {
              upVoters: this.userId
            },
            $inc: {
              downvote: -1,
              upvote: 1
            }
          }
        );
      }
      Articles.update(this._id, {$addToSet: {upVoters: Meteor.userId()}, $inc: {upvote: 1}});
    }
  },

  "click .downvote": function(){
    var articles = Articles.findOne({ _id: this._id });
    if( articles ) {
      if (_.contains(articles.upVoters, this.userId)) {
        Articles.update({
             _id: this._id
          },
          {
            $pull: {
              upVoters: this.userId
            },
            $addToSet: {
              downVoters: this.userId
            },
            $inc: {
              downvote: 1,
              upvote: -1
            }
          }
        );
      }
      Articles.update(this._id, {$addToSet: {downVoters: Meteor.userId()}, $inc: {downvote: 1}});
    }
  }
});
```

And HTML:

```
<template name="articleOutput">
    <div class="outputBoxHome" >
      <div class="vote">
        <div class="upvote">

        </div>
        <div class="downvote">

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="outputBoxHomeContent">
        <a href="/articles/{{_id}}"><h4>{{title}}</h4></a>
      </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

With this code the user can upvote and it will be added as well as their name to upVoter and vice versa

**EDIT**

I fixed it by using $.inArray instead of _.contains

```
if ($.inArray(articles.upVoters, this.userId)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it by using $.inArray instead of _.contains.